# Erro ao obter URL no Firebase, Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firestore

Boa noite!!! Estou desenvolvendo um app no qual é possível a postagem de fotos. O usuário abre a câmera (ou pega da galeria com ImagePicker) e clica em um botão no AppBar. Quando pressionado, o app volta para a tela inicial e é feito o Upload da imagem no Firestorage. É possível colocar várias informações nessa foto, como nome do responsável etc, as quais vão ficar armazenadas no Firestore em uma coleção "fotos". Porém, quando faço o upload da foto, todas as informações aparecem no Firestore, menos a URL da imagem. Quando tento fazer o upload de uma nova imagem, o app processo tudo certo, porém a URL que aparece na coleção, é da imagem anterior.

Segue o código:

```
Future _uploadImagem(Modelo modelo) async {

    String nomeImagem = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    StorageReference pastaRaiz = storage.ref();
    StorageReference arquivo = pastaRaiz
      .child("fotos")
      .child(nomeImagem + ".jpg");

    // Recuperar url da imagem
    StorageUploadTask task = arquivo.putFile(_imagem);
    task.onComplete.then((StorageTaskSnapshot snap){
      _recuperarUrl(snap);
    });

    // Coloca os dados da imagem no Cloud FireStore
    Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
    db.collection("fotos")
    .document(nomeImagem + ".jpg")
    .setData(modelo.toMap());
  }

  // Recuperar url
  Future _recuperarUrl(StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot) async {
    String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      urlImagemRecuperada = url;
    });
  }

  // Radio
  String _escolhaZona;
  String _escolhaArea;
  String _escolhaEdificacao;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Upload da Foto"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.beenhere),
            onPressed: (){
              if(_imagem == null){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }else{

                // Instancia as informações da imagem

                Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
                String nomeLog = _nomeLog.text;
                String numero = _numero.text;
                String complemento = _complemento.text;
                String municipio = _municipio.text;
                String estado = _estado.text;
                String metrosQuadrados = _metrosQuadrados.text;
                String nomeResponsavel = _nomeResponsavel.text;


                modelo.nomeLog = nomeLog;
                modelo.numero = numero;
                modelo.complemento = complemento;
                modelo.municipio = municipio;
                modelo.estado = estado;
                modelo.metrosQuadrados = metrosQuadrados;
                modelo.responsalvel = nomeResponsavel;
                modelo.edificacao = _escolhaEdificacao;
                modelo.area = _escolhaArea;
                modelo.zona = _escolhaZona;
                modelo.url = urlImagemRecuperada;

                _uploadImagem(modelo);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que a url seja recuperada e colocada na coleção juntamente com as outras informações ?

Minha classe Modelo ficou da seguinte forma:

```
 class Modelo {
  String _url;
  String _nomeLog;
  String _numero;
  String _complemento;
  String _municipio;
  String _estado;
  String _zona;
  String _area;
  String _edificacao;
  String _metrosQuadrados;
  String _responsavel;

  Modelo();
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "urlImagem":this.url,
      "nomeLog": this.nomeLog,
      "numero":this.numero,
      "complemento":this.complemento,
      "municipio":this.municipio,
      "estado":this.estado,
      "zona":this.zona,
      "area":this.area,
      "edificacao":this.edificacao,
      "metrosQuadrados":this.metrosQuadrados,
      "responsavel":this.responsavel,
    };
    return map;
  }

  String get url => _url;
  set url(String value){
    _url = value;
  }

  String get nomeLog => _nomeLog;
  set nomeLog(String value){
    _nomeLog=value;
  }

  String get numero => _numero;
  set numero(String value){
    _numero = value;
  }

  String get complemento => _complemento;
  set complemento(String value){
    _complemento = value;
  }

  String get municipio => _municipio;
  set municipio(String value){
    _municipio = value;
  }

  String get estado => _estado;
  set estado(String value){
    _estado = value;
  }

  String get zona => _zona;
  set zona(String value){
    _zona = value;
  }

  String get area => _area;
  set area(String value){
    _area = value;
  }

  String get edificacao => _edificacao;
  set edificacao(String value){
    _edificacao = value;
  }

  String get metrosQuadrados => _metrosQuadrados;
  set metrosQuadrados(String value){
    _metrosQuadrados = value;
  }

  String get responsavel => _responsavel;
  set responsalvel(String value){
    _responsavel = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Como está o método `toMap()` da classe Modelo?

Comment: Bom diaa!! Acabei de editar o post colocando como está minha classe modelo

Comment: Beleza, vou dar uma testada aquo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está no método `_uploadImagem` você está usando o `.then()` de uma função async, dessa forma, o seu `setData` vai ser executado antes do retorno da sua `task.onComplete`.

No caso você precisa utilizar o `await` que vai aguardar o retorno da sua `task` e ai sim fazer o que precisa.

```
Future _uploadImagem(Modelo modelo) async {

    String nomeImagem = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    StorageReference pastaRaiz = storage.ref();
    StorageReference arquivo = pastaRaiz
      .child("fotos")
      .child(nomeImagem + ".jpg");

    // Recuperar url da imagem
    StorageUploadTask task = arquivo.putFile(_imagem);
    final snapshot = await task.onComplete;     
    model.url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    // Coloca os dados da imagem no Cloud FireStore
    Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
    await db.collection("fotos")
    .document(nomeImagem + ".jpg")
    .setData(modelo.toMap());
  }
```

> Obs. 1: Não sei ao certo o que vai ser retornado em `final snapshot =
>   await task.onComplete` então usei como FINAL, você ajusta ai de acordo
>   com o que precisa.
>
> Obs. 2: Você está preenchendo a variável `urlImagemRecuperada` após
>   ter preenchido toda sua model... Então você precisa também preencher a
>   sua model com a url recuperada antes de salvar os dados...

Precisa também modificar seu click do botão:

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.beenhere),
  onPressed: () async {
    if(_imagem == null){
    Navigator.pop(context);
    }else{

    // Instancia as informações da imagem

    Modelo modelo = new Modelo();
    String nomeLog = _nomeLog.text;
    String numero = _numero.text;
    String complemento = _complemento.text;
    String municipio = _municipio.text;
    String estado = _estado.text;
    String metrosQuadrados = _metrosQuadrados.text;
    String nomeResponsavel = _nomeResponsavel.text;


    modelo.nomeLog = nomeLog;
    modelo.numero = numero;
    modelo.complemento = complemento;
    modelo.municipio = municipio;
    modelo.estado = estado;
    modelo.metrosQuadrados = metrosQuadrados;
    modelo.responsalvel = nomeResponsavel;
    modelo.edificacao = _escolhaEdificacao;
    modelo.area = _escolhaArea;
    modelo.zona = _escolhaZona;

    await _uploadImagem(modelo);

    Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  },
)
```

Outra coisa, porque você está criando GET/SET para todas as propriedades da sua model?

Em Flutter/Dart você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
class Modelo {

  Modelo({this.url, this.nomeLog, this.numero, this.complemento, this.municipio, this.estado, this.zona, this.area, this.edificacao, this.metrosQuadrados, this.responsavel});

  String url;
  String nomeLog;
  String numero;
  String complemento;
  String municipio;
  String estado;
  String zona;
  String area;
  String edificacao;
  String metrosQuadrados;
  String responsavel;

  void meuMetodo(){  
    print(url);
  }

}
```

Comment: Mas no caso, aquele snapshot que recebe o task.onComplete vai ser passado no recuperaUrl ?

Comment: Com o _recuperarUrl fora do then, o documento não é criado no firestore :(

Comment: Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _UploadFotoState#19dbc(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Comment: Fiz algumas modificações na minha resposta, veja se resolve. Caso de algum problema relacionado ao `await _uploadImagem(modelo);`, no click do botão, tente remover o `await`.

Comment: Deu certoo!!!! Muito obrigado, você é o cara!